# Send email from command line in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, console, twig

I need to render a twig template from a command class in symfony2.

```php
namespace IT\bBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class CronCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('send:emails')
            ->setDescription('Envio programado de emails');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('bla bla')
            ->setFrom('x@x.com')
            ->setTo('x@gmail.com')
            ->setCharset('UTF-8')
            ->setContentType('text/html')       
            ->setBody($this->renderView('mainBundle:Email:default.html.twig'));

        $this->getContainer()->get('mailer')->send($message);
        $output->writeln('Enviado!');
    }
}
```

But when I execute the command `php app/console send:emails` I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method `IT\bBundle\Command\CronCommand::renderView()`

How can I render the view?

Comment: Just a foot note: if you plan to send bulk emails this is not the way to do it. If it's just once in a while it will be ok.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It's because renderView is method of class Controller. Instead of that try:

```
$this->getContainer()->get('templating')->render(...);
```

Answer (score 18):

Change

```php
$this->renderView()
```

to

```php
$this->getContainer()->get('templating')->render()
```

Answer (score 9):

Maybe, not exactly the question you ask, but for sure - important.

Please, do remember that if you want to send emails via Command call, you need to flushQueue.

```
$mailer = $container->get('mailer');
$spool = $mailer->getTransport()->getSpool();
$transport = $container->get('swiftmailer.transport.real');
$spool->flushQueue($transport);
```

Comment: Hi, this seems to be not neccessary for all Symfony versions. I use v3.6 and use Commands sending emails without flushing the queue.